# UItableView data from Plist

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, plist

I have a plist with thousands of Array into it.and each array contains Dictionary with 51 items in it.thats means total of some 40,000 data,I have populated into the `UITableView` correctly .IF I enter around 10 `Array` into the `UITableView`..its display the rows in good view...but when I go beyond like 40 arrays ..the `UITableView` gets weird.you can't even understand.
[image: first]
.
.

and `UITableView` is below..

[image: sec]
.

I have also tried to Exapanded rows for each section.that also not working for me ..what should I do?

**EDIT** code

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sam" ofType:@"plist"];

//Load the file in a dictionnary
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

self.myData = dict;

//SORTING THE DICTIONARY    
NSArray *dicoArray = [[self.myData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];

self.mySections = dicoArray;

NSLog(@"path values%@",tableDict);


}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{



return [self.mySections count];



}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
 {
    if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
    {

NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *dataInSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];
return [dataInSection count];
    }
    return 1;
  }
return 1;
  }


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
 return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
}


-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return self.mySections;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];



NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];

NSDictionary *dataForSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *array=dataForSection.allKeys;

cell.textLabel.text = [[dataForSection allKeys] objectAtIndex:row];    
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[dataForSection valueForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   return cell;     
 }
```

this code works fine If I take less Array say 10Array with 51 values into it...but when I take more...screen shows like this

**edit**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
    <key>BUTTER,WITH SALT</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Alpha_Carot_(µg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Ash_(g)</key>
            <string>2.11</string>
            <key>Beta_Carot_(µg)</key>
            <string>158</string>
            <key>Beta_Crypt_(µg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Calcium_(mg)</key>
            <string>24</string>
            <key>Carbohydrt_(g)</key>
            <string>0.06</string>
            <key>Cholestrl_(mg)</key>
            <string>215</string>
            <key>Choline_Tot_ (mg)</key>
            <string>18.8</string>
            <key>Copper_mg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Energ_Kcal</key>
            <string>717</string>
            <key>FA_Mono_(g)</key>
            <string>21.021</string>
            <key>FA_Poly_(g)</key>
            <string>3.043</string>
            <key>FA_Sat_(g)</key>
            <string>51.368</string>
            <key>Fiber_TD_(g)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Folate_DFE_(µg)</key>
            <string>3</string>
            <key>Folate_Tot_(µg)</key>
            <string>3</string>
            <key>Folic_Acid_(µg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Food_Folate_(µg)</key>
            <string>3</string>
            <key>GmWt_1</key>
            <string>227</string>
            <key>GmWt_2</key>
            <string>14.2</string>
            <key>GmWt_Desc1</key>
            <string>1 cup</string>
            <key>GmWt_Desc2</key>
            <string>1 tbsp</string>
            <key>Iron_(mg)</key>
            <string>0.02</string>
            <key>Lipid_Tot_(g)</key>
            <string>81.11</string>
            <key>Lut+Zea_ (µg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Lycopene_(µg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Magnesium_(mg)</key>
            <string>2</string>
            <key>Manganese_(mg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Niacin_(mg)</key>
            <string>0.042</string>
            <key>Panto_Acid_mg)</key>
            <string>0.11</string>
            <key>Phosphorus_(mg)</key>
            <string>24</string>
            <key>Potassium_(mg)</key>
            <string>24</string>
            <key>Protein_(g)</key>
            <string>0.85</string>
            <key>Refuse_Pct</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Retinol_(µg)</key>
            <string>671</string>
            <key>Riboflavin_(mg)</key>
            <string>0.034</string>
            <key>Selenium_(µg)</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>Sodium_(mg)</key>
            <string>714</string>
            <key>Sugar_Tot_(g)</key>
            <string>0.06</string>

        </dict>

    </array>
    <key>BUTTER,WHIPPED,WITH SALT</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Alpha_Carot_(µg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Ash_(g)</key>
            <string>2.11</string>
            <key>Beta_Carot_(µg)</key>
            <string>158</string>
            <key>Beta_Crypt_(µg)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>Calcium_(mg)</key>
            <string>24</string>
            <key>Carbohydrt_(g)</key>
            <string>0.06</string>
            <key>Cholestrl_(mg)</key>
            <string>219</string>
            <key>Choline_Tot_ (mg)</key>
            <string>18.8</string>
            <key>Copper_mg)</key>
            <string>0.016</string>
            <key>Energ_Kcal</key>
            <string>717</string>
            <key>FA_Mono_(g)</key>
            <string>23.426</string>
            <key>FA_Poly_(g)</key>
            <string>3.012</string>
            <key>FA_Sat_(g)</key>
            <string>50.489</string>
            <key>Fiber_TD_(g)</key>
            <string>0</string>
            </dict></array>
      </dict></plist>
```

Comment: Please post the code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Paste your cellforrow code

Comment: @ParamasivanSamuttiram check now question,..I have edit my code....ITs only creates problem when I take many Array

Comment: @Rajneesh071 heck now question,..I have edit my code....ITs only creates problem when I take many Array

Comment: can you please tell me in what format you want...

Comment: ya Arrays should display on the  sections field, and dictionary values as within the rows of that

Comment: first of all its now complete code.... this code is just for cell.textLabel.text and cell.detailTextLabel.text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now see what the problem is. You have an index selection that is way too big.

You can remove this by removing the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView method.

If you really want this, you can format all the strings to not be bigger than a few characters like:

```
-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSMutableArray *shorterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for( NSString *sectionTitle in self.mySections ){
        NSString *shortSectionTitle;
        if( sectionTitle.length > 4 ){
            shortSectionTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@..", [sectionTitle substringToIndex:4]];
        } else {
            shortSectionTitle = sectionTitle;
        }
        [shorterArray addObject:shortSectionTitle];
    }
    return shorterArray;
}
```

If you need more help, let me know

Comment: not working..check plist in question...its just a 1% of plist ...like this plist going on.

Comment: ya if i take 5-6 array of dictionary output is fine...when i take more this is happening

Comment: ya its its helpful!..but problem 1) its not display full list of Arrays (giving half and starting from mid) 2) its not displaying the rows

Comment: and if i enter the expanded rows code its giving me rows fine...but problem still array list in around half

Comment: I removed if ([tableView canCollapseSection:section]) and 
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section]). I have no idea what this is suppose to do, but this is not working.

Comment: sorry sorry that way my mistake...somewhere in key it was <key>>butter...that was the mistake...now its working fine

Comment: search plist problem..help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985379/uisearchview-not-displaying-search-values

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dataForSection = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *array=dataForSection.allKeys;

cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];    
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[dataForSection objectForKey:[array objectAtIndex:row]];
```

Comment: ] -[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6863db0
2012-12-13 12:48:37.169 PlistFile[1028:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString allKeys]:

Comment: PlistFile[253:f803] value (
    ">MILK,DRY,NONFAT,REG,WO/ ADDED VIT A & VITAMIN D",
    ">MILK,SHEEP,FLUID",
    "BUTTER OIL,ANHYDROUS",
    "BUTTER,WHIPPED,WITH SALT",
    "BUTTER,WITH SALT",
    "CHEESE FD,COLD PK,AMERICAN",
    "CHEESE FD,PAST PROCESS,AMERICAN,VITAMIN D FORT",
    "CHEESE FD,PAST PROCESS,SWISS",
    "CHEESE SPRD,PAST PROCESS,AMERICAN",
    "CHEESE,BLUE",
    "CHEESE,BRICK",
    "CHEESE,BRIE",
    "CHEESE,CAMEMBERT",
    "CHEESE,CARAWAY",
    "CHEESE,CHEDDAR",
    "CHEESE,CHESHIRE",
   }

Comment: ok now what is the nslog of this dic,,, NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

Comment: YOGURT,VANILLA,LOFAT,11 GRAMS PROT PER 8 OZ" =     (
                {
            "Alpha_Carot_(\U00b5g)" = 0;
            "Ash_(g)" = "1.02";
            "Beta_Carot_(\U00b5g)" = 2;
            "Beta_Crypt_(\U00b5g)" = 0;
            "Calcium_(mg)" = 171;
            "Carbohydrt_(g)" = "13.8";
            
            "            "FA_Mono_(g)" = "0.343";
            "FA_Poly_(g)" = "0.036";}
            "FA_Sat_(g)" = "0.806";
            "Fiber_TD_(g)" = 0;
            "Folate_DFE_(\U00b5g)" = 11;
            "Folate_Tot_(\U00b5g)" = 11;
            "Folic_Acid_(\U00b5g)" = 0;

Comment: man its giving me correct one nslog..And if i take less array in plist..cellforrowatindexpath also works fine...but when I take more Array...the image is above in question

Comment: just replace this NSDictionary *dataForSection = [dic objectAtIndex:section];

Comment: there is nothing objectAtindex for Dic, if i take ObjectAtKey...crashes with bad access.. :(

Comment: NSDictionary *dataForSection = [[dic objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21060/discussion-between-rajneesh071-and-christien)

Comment: search plist problem..help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985379/uisearchview-not-displaying-search-values

Answer (score -1):

Try removing if (cell == nil) { } condition. That is declare, cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; outside if brackets.

Comment: Nothing changes...when I remove (cell==nil)..same output

Comment: In general, removing this clause will make your code less efficient because it forces a new cell to be initialized every time it appears on the screen. UITableView has a cache that reuses cells and this makes it perform faster, especially with this many rows. Cells should only be initialized when dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: returns nil.